# Rotating axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I've been using matplotlib to rotate the axes for an animation. So this is what I use as the update function for FuncAnimation:

```
def update(i, fig, ax):
    ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=i)
    return fig, ax
```

So each frame, the axes rotate by an angle i. However, this rotation doesn't take place about the origin of the axes, but about some middle point. How can I rotate the axes so that the origin stays fixed in place in the plot? Is there a way to choose which point the axes rotate about?

Thanks!